# Sqoop import runs for 25 hours for a table with 32 million rows.

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, sqoop

I tried to Sqoop a few tables with 30+ millions of rows and it took around 91241 sec, which is ~25 hours to complete the map tasks. Details as follow :

14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 222.1807 GB in 91,241.711 seconds (2.4935 MB/sec)
14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 32419937 records.

What could be the issue and how can I improve the speed?

Comment: 13/12/31 07:16:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1386368977819_0274 completed successfully

Comment: 14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 27
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=89714
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=238564739552
                HDFS: Number of read operations=4
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2

Comment: Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Other local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=91232432
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0

Comment: Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=32419937
                Map output records=32419937
                Input split bytes=87
                Spilled Records=0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=639519
                CPU time spent (ms)=12879390
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=286007296
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1572376576
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=95420416

Comment: File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=238564739552
14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 222.1807 GB in 91,241.711 seconds (2.4935 MB/sec)
14/01/01 08:37:12 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 32419937 records.

Answer (score 0):

use primary key based sqoop imports by minimum and maximum limit range within the table for multiple imports from a single table.